# change selenium hub default port docker-compose

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

I have multiple jenkins jobs, each attempt to start a selenium standalone container, although when multiple jobs run in parallel in the same jenkins slave, it throws the following error:

```
0.0.0.0:4444 failed: port is already allocated
```

Which is fair enough because the default port for the selenium standalone is set to 4444. My question is how I override the selenium standalone port? I thought it was related to `ports: ...` but clearly not... any ideas?

Below is my docker-compose file:

```
maven:
  build: "."
  links:
    - "selenium:selenium"
  working_dir: /code/
  volumes:
    - ".:/code"
  entrypoint:
  - mvn
  - verify
  - -Dwebdriver.remote.url=http://selenium:4444/wd/hub
selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

I have for instance another docker-compose file, slightly different, for instance:

```
maven_2:
  build: "."
  links:
    - "selenium_2:selenium_2"
  working_dir: /code/
  volumes:
    - ".:/code"
  entrypoint:
  - mvn
  - verify
  - -Dsome.additional.tags=test
  - -Dwebdriver.remote.url=http://selenium_2:4444/wd/hub
selenium_2:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

Comment: In the second compose you can define: ports: - "4445:4444". If you want to change default port you need to create your own docker image FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

Comment: cool, I've had to create my own image and have the port as an argument... thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: could you add the Dockerfile for the image you've created? thanks!